# How to convert a string to an integral number type array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I want to convert the following `string` to an array of an integral number type.

```
string str = "-9007199254740985";
```

I tried `str.ToArray().ToString();` but did not get the right conversion.

Comment: `var stringArray = new string[] { "-9007199254740985" };`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the `string` to an array, you can do it like this.

```
var array = new string[] { str };
```

However, if you want an array of `long`, you have to convert your `string` first.

```
var number = long.Parse(str);
```

Then you can add it to an array.

```
var array = new long[] { number };
```

Note that you cannot use an `int` here, because your number [exceeds its range](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/integral-numeric-types).

Comment: how to convert to from "9007199254740985" to [-9007199254740985] or "[-9007199254740985]"

Comment: What do you mean by that? Do you want to convert the string to an integer? An integer array? Or do you just want to a string `"-9007199254740985"` with brackets around it`["-9007199254740985"]`?

Comment: Yes an integer array. [-9007199254740985]

Comment: Adapted your question and my answer according to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will convert the string to character array.

```
string input = "welcome";
char[] chars = input.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: how to convert to from "9007199254740985"  to [-9007199254740985]                                
 or "[-9007199254740985]"